# return statement not responding what should i do

Tags: python, if-statement, return, return-value, fizzbuzz

```py
def fizz_buzz(num):
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
        return "Fizz Buzz"
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        return "Fizz"
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        return "Buzz"
    return num

fizz_buzz(15)
```

1. I don't know why my `return` statement is working.
2. Conditions are aligned properly
3. I referred this code:

[image]

4. He used `input` instead I used `num`
5. I don't want to use `input` shown in reference code

Comment: Your code looks good to me. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code runs fine. If you're wondering why you're not getting an output, you have to print the value the function returns.

```py
print(fizz_buzz(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to print them? there is not syntactical error that I can find

```
def fizz_buzz(num):
 if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
     return "Fizz Buzz"
 elif num % 3 == 0:
     return "Fizz"
 elif num % 5 == 0:
     return "Buzz"
 return num


print(fizz_buzz(7))
```